# Bootstrap-table2 How to make custom text search filter on String month and date?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am currently making a BootstrapTable with one column with a dataField of birthday, which is a string in the format of "day/month" or "3/10" for October 3rd as an example. I successfully made a formatter which transformed every string like "3/10" to show up as a string like "October 3rd" on the table. I want to add a filter: textFilter and currently using a default. The problem is, if the user types in "October", nothing shows up. You type in "10" for October 3rd to show up. I am trying to implement a custom filter such that if if the user types in a substring like "Octo", all examples of October birthdays would show up and non October dates would be filtered. How can I implement something like this? This is my first attempt at trying to implement something like this below.

```
filterByPrice = (filterVal, data) => {
        if (filterVal) {
            var fields = data.birthday.split('/');
            var month = parseInt(fields[1]);
            var day = parseInt(fields[0]);
            
            switch(month){
                case 1:
                    month = "January";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    month = "February";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    month = "March";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    month = "April";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    month = "May";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    month = "June";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    month = "July";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    month = "August";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    month = "September";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    month = "October";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    month = "November";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    month = "December";
            }
            var dateString = month + " " + day
            data.filter(dateString.includes(filterVal));
        }
        return data;

const {columns} = {
            columns: [{
                dataField: 'birthday',
                text: 'Birthday',
                filter: textFilter({
                    onFilter: this.birthdayFilter
                }),
                formatter: birthdayFormatter, //successfuly transforms "10/3" into "October 3rd" function.
            }]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out there is a parameter called filterValue that searches based on the formatter.

```
{
    dataField: 'birthday',
    text: 'Birthday',          
    filter: textFilter(),
    filterValue: birthdayFormatter,
    formatter: birthdayFormatter
}
```